# How can I scrape text within paragraph tag with some other tags then within the paragraph text?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to scrape info in a paragraph tag. the

tag has some other tags in it. I will show you in the below code.

Here is the

Here is the html page to be scraped:

```
<div class="thecontent">
<p>Here&rsquo;s the schedule of matches for the weekend.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Saturday, August 17</strong></p>

<p>Achara vs. Buad, <a href="@">ftv</a>, <a href="https://someothertv">HTlive</a>, <a href="http://www.anothertv target="_blank">Se</a> &mdash;&nbsp;Have enjoy it and celebrate it</p>

<p>pritos vs. baola, <a href="@">ftv</a>, <a href="https://someothertv">HTlive</a>, <a href="http://www.anothertv target="_blank">Se</a> &mdash;&nbsp;Have enjoy it and celebrate it</p>


<p>timpao vs. quadrsa, <a href="@">ftv</a>, <a href="https://someothertv">HTlive</a>, <a href="http://www.anothertv target="_blank">Se</a> &mdash;&nbsp;Have enjoy it and celebrate it</p>

<p><strong>Sunday, August 18</strong></p>



<p>Achara vs. timpao, <a href="@">ftv</a>, <a href="https://someothertv">HTlive</a>, <a href="http://www.anothertv target="_blank">Se</a> &mdash;&nbsp;Have enjoy it and celebrate it</p>

<p>pritos vs. qaudra, <a href="@">ftv</a>, <a href="https://someothertv">HTlive</a>, <a href="http://www.anothertv target="_blank">Se</a> &mdash;&nbsp;Have enjoy it and celebrate it</p>


<p>timpao vs. Buad, <a href="@">ftv</a>, <a href="https://someothertv">HTlive</a>, <a href="http://www.anothertv target="_blank">Se</a> &mdash;&nbsp;Have enjoy it and celebrate it</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Monday, August 19</strong></p>


<p>Achara vs. Buad, <a href="@">ftv</a>, <a href="https://someothertv">HTlive</a>, <a href="http://www.anothertv target="_blank">Se</a> &mdash;&nbsp;Have enjoy it and celebrate it</p>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p></div></body></html>
```

I used the following python code:

```
import bs4,requests

getnwp = requests.get('https://url')
nwpcontent = getnwp.content
sp2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(nwpcontent, 'html5lib')
pta = sp2.find('div', class_ = 'thecontent').find_all('p')
        for i in range(len(pta)):
            if pta[i].get_text().find("vs") != -1:
                print (pta[i].get_text())
```

with that above info, I wanted to extract only match between teams and the date it is happening. and the little message like below:

> Saturday, August 17
>
> Achara vs. timpao,  — Have enjoy it and celebrate it
>
> pritos vs. baola, — Have enjoy it and celebrate it
>
> timpao vs. quadrsa, — Have enjoy it and celebrate it
>
> Sunday, August 18
>
> Achara vs. timpao, — Have enjoy it and celebrate it
>
> pritos vs. qaudra, — Have enjoy it and celebrate it
>
> timpao vs. Buad,  — Have enjoy it and celebrate it
>
> Monday, August 19
>
> Achara vs. Buad, — Have enjoy it and celebrate it

I mean I don't want the information about tv broadcasting it ( or the info in the anchor tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what actual source is like. For example given you could remove a tags and use `:has` and `:not(:empty)` to target. Requires bs4 4.7.1+

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://worldsoccertalk.com/2019/08/16/epl-commentator-assignments-nbc-sports-gameweek-2-3/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for a in soup("a"):
    a.decompose()

for i in soup.select('.thecontent p:has(strong:not(:contains("SEE MORE"))), .thecontent p:has(strong:not(:contains("SEE MORE"))) ~ p:not(:empty)'):
    data = i.text.strip()
    if data:
        if ' vs. ' in data:
            items = data.split(',')
            print(', '.join([items[0], items[-1].split('—')[1]]))
        else:
            print(data)
```

---

[image]

Comment: No output is displayed. using the above data, could you please display any output using the code you posted?

Comment: can you supply the original url then? If you run my code exactly as is there is output.

Comment: Here is the original url https://worldsoccertalk.com/2019/08/16/epl-commentator-assignments-nbc-sports-gameweek-2-3/

Comment: but some of the them were not stripped!

Comment: thanks this works! only some minor adjustment is needed

Comment: how can i remove this unwanted "and" in the output: West Ham vs. Manchester City,   "and"  — Jim Proudfoot and Andy Townsend ?

Comment: please try edit. Wasn't sure if you also meant last _and_

Comment: still output contains unwanted and "coming from the anchor tag text"

Comment: Please explain what an example of this text looks like

Comment: after teams displayed there is an "and" then followed  —

Comment: Not for the url you provided. Which url does this occur for please?

Comment: **same this url**

Comment: this is the output from the above code : Wolves vs. Manchester United   **and**  — Martin Tyler and Danny Higginbotham

Comment: Weird. I do not see that.

Comment: thanks finally worked :). but one more here I tried to wrap it as function like this

Comment: def matches(): 
 
 for a in soup("a"):
  a.decompose()

 for j in soup.select('.thecontent p:has(strong:not(:contains("SEE MORE"))), .thecontent p:has(strong:not(:contains("SEE MORE"))) ~ p:not(:empty)'):
  data = j.text.strip()
  print(data)
  if data:
   if ' vs. ' in data:
    items = data.split(',')
    return (', '.join([items[j], items[-1].split('—')[1]]))
   else:
    return data

Comment: only p with strong is returned!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198093/discussion-between-hanan-and-qharr).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the paragraph that has the content also includes the prompt ", - Have enjoy it and celebrate it" so when you retrieve its content its always added. What you could do is remove the tailing of the string by doing something like

```
if len(pta[i] > 33):
  pta[i].get_text()[:-33]
```

That way you will remove the last 33 characters of the result string.

Comment: btw character count would always change as more info is published!

Comment: using this : if len(pta[i] > 33):
  pta[i].get_text()[:-33] no output is displayed!

Comment: i assume that `pta[i].get_text()` contains the string 'Achara vs. timpao, — Have enjoy it and celebrate it'. You can obtain the substring in several ways, one of them is by getting the begin/end index, in our case `[:-34]` (not -33) this gets from index 0 to index 34 counting from end to begining.
If you want to see the output add  `print(pta[i].get_text()[:-34])`